# Using Regex formula (and inside array) to make it check for a pattern on three cells (using OR) on the same time

Tags: arrays, excel, regex, vba, excel-formula

I have used this expression on the cell (K3) `=RegexMatch(C3,"\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")`.
 and then later used it inside an array to evaluate the destination range respectively with the values of column (C).
**I need** to adapt the below code and formula to make it check three cells (using OR) on the same time.
 I mean check the pattern on cells e.g `("C3" or "F3" or "G3"`) if match in any one of the cited cells then result of formula is true and vice versa.
I tried `=RegexMatch((C3,F3,G3),"\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")` but it has no effect regarding cells (F3,G3).

```
Sub Regex_with_three_cells()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, x As Long, r_in As Variant, r_out()
    
     Set ws = ActiveSheet
     lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     r_in = ws.Range("C3:C" & lr).Value
     
     ReDim r_out(1 To UBound(r_in), 1 To 1)
    
    For x = LBound(r_in) To UBound(r_in)
        r_out(x, 1) = RegexMatch(r_in(x, 1), "\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")
    Next
    
    ws.Range("K3:K" & lr).Value = Application.Index(r_out, 0, 1)

End Sub

Public Function RegexMatch(str, pat) As Boolean
    Static RE As Object
     If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      RE.Pattern = pat
       RegexMatch = RE.Test(str)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted solution:

```
Sub Regex_with_three_cells()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, x As Long, r_in As Variant, r_out()
    
     Set ws = ActiveSheet
     lr = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     r_in = ws.Range("C3:G" & lr).Value2
     
     ReDim r_out(1 To UBound(r_in), 1 To 1)
    
    For x = LBound(r_in) To UBound(r_in)
        If RegexMatch(r_in(x, 1)) Or RegexMatch(r_in(x, 4)) _
                                   Or RegexMatch(r_in(x, 5)) Then
            r_out(x, 1) = True
        End If
    Next
    
    ws.Range("K3:K" & lr).Value2 = r_out

End Sub

Public Function RegexMatch(str) As Boolean
    Static RE As Object
     If RE Is Nothing Then Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      RE.Pattern = "\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b" 'place the pattern here to make 
                                                 'the call more compact
       RegexMatch = RE.Test(str)
End Function
```

If you also need to write `False` in case of no match, the code can be easily adapted using `Else: r_out(x, 1) = False`...

**Edited**:

To use a formula able to deal with values of the three columns (of course, on the same row), you should use **the above function** and the next formula:

```
=IF(OR(RegexMatch(C31),RegexMatch(F3),RegexMatch(G3)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Each `RegMatch` function will be evaluated as Boolean return and `IF` will return accordingly...

It is also possible to make the function able to accept multiple cells (ranges) and and process each of them, returning `True` and exiting when a cell processing returns `RE.Test(CStr(cell.value)))` = `True`... Its call, as UDF, can be transformed in:

```
  =RegexMatch(C3,F3,G3)
```

Comment: as a learning purpose , Is the `Regex formula` itself  `=RegexMatch(C3,"\b[Mm]od(?!erate).*\b[hH]\b")` ,can be adapted to using OR.

Comment: @Waleed Yes, it certainly can be converted. I will show you how, tomorrow. Only now I am at home and it is too late to open my laptop...

Comment: Excellent clarification , tested and works perfectly 